# Flutter StreamBuilder stuck on state waiting after re-navigating back to the page

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am new to flutter and I have a problem with StreamBuilder. When starting, snapshots from firestore are returned but when I navigate to another page, then return back to the page, the connection state of the snapshot is stuck in waiting. When hot reloading or refreshing the page, the data is shown and works fine. The problem only happens when re-navigating back to the page. I think that since it does not add new data or edit the data, the streambuilder will not be updated and won't rebuild.

[Initial streambuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8MfG.png)

[After re-navigating back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MroVb.png)

I also used DataTable to show my data in table form, the following code might be a little long.

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: providerDBsnaps,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return const LinearProgressIndicator();
        case ConnectionState.active:
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data!.docs;

            providers = documents
                .map((e) =>
                    ProviderList.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
                .toList();

            List<DataRow> providerListItems() {
              List<DataRow> providerList = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < providers.length; i++) {
                bool status = providers[i].status;
                DataRow dataRow =
                    DataRow(onSelectChanged: (bool? newVal) {}, cells: [
                  DataCell(Container(
                    width: 30,
                    child: Text((i + 1).toString()),
                  )),
                  DataCell(Container(
                    width: 120,
                    child: Text(providers[i].name),
                  )),
                  DataCell(Container(
                    width: 200,
                    child: Text(providers[i].address),
                  )),
                  DataCell(
                    Container(
                        width: 120, child: Text(providers[i].contact)),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Container(width: 100, child: Text(providers[i].phone)),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    MouseRegion(
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        width: 42,
                        height: 22,
                        child: FlutterSwitch(
                          value: providers[i].status,
                          width: 40.0,
                          height: 20.0,
                          borderRadius: 30.0,
                          onToggle: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                        title: const CustomText(
                                          text: "Warning",
                                          weight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          size: 22,
                                        ),
                                        content: const CustomText(
                                          text:
                                              "Are you sure you want to change the status?",
                                          size: 16,
                                        ),
                                        actions: [
                                          TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              status = val;
                                              providerDB
                                                  .doc(providers[i].id)
                                                  .update(
                                                      {'p_status': status});
                                              Navigator.pop(context);
                                            },
                                            child: const CustomText(
                                                text: 'Yes'),
                                          ),
                                          TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              Navigator.pop(context);
                                            },
                                            child: const CustomText(
                                                text: 'No'),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ));
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataCell(Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          onPressed: () {
                            menuController
                                .changeActiveitemTo(EditingPageName);
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ProviderEditPage(
                                    existing: providers[i]),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                      title: const CustomText(
                                        text: "Delete Notice",
                                        weight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        size: 22,
                                      ),
                                      content: const CustomText(
                                        text:
                                            "Are you sure you want to delete the item?",
                                        size: 16,
                                      ),
                                      actions: [
                                        TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            providerDB
                                                .doc(providers[i]
                                                    .id
                                                    .toString())
                                                .delete();
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          },
                                          child:
                                              const CustomText(text: 'Yes'),
                                        ),
                                        TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          },
                                          child:
                                              const CustomText(text: 'No'),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ));
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ))
                ]);
                providerList.add(dataRow);
              }
              return providerList;
            }

            return Container(
              height: 550,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        offset: const Offset(0, 6),
                        color: lightGrey.withOpacity(.1),
                        blurRadius: 12),
                  ],
                  border: Border.all(color: lightGrey, width: .5)),
              child: DataTable(
                columnSpacing: 0,
                showCheckboxColumn: false,
                columns: const [
                  DataColumn(
                    label: CustomText(
                      text: "No.",
                      weight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: CustomText(
                      text: "Name",
                      weight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: CustomText(
                      text: "Address",
                      weight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: CustomText(
                      text: "Contact Person",
                      weight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: CustomText(
                      text: "Phone Number",
                      weight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: CustomText(
                      text: "Status",
                      weight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: CustomText(
                      text: "Tools",
                      weight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                rows: providerListItems(),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const Text('No data...');
          }
        case ConnectionState.done:
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        default:
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
      }
    });
```

}

Is there something that I did wrong? Or is it a bug? Is the problem like I thought it is that data is not updated, so stream builder only builds once? If so, can you provide a solution for me, I can't seem to find the solution... Thank you!

**--> EDIT**

Initialization of providerDBsnaps

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  providerDBsnaps = providerDB.snapshots();
  providerDBsnaps.listen((snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.docs;

    providers = documents
        .map((e) => ProviderList.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
  }
});
}
```

Comment: before `switch (...)` add `print(snapshot)`, what do you see on the logs?

Comment: FIRST EXECUTION: AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(ConnectionState.active, Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot', null, null). AFTER RENAVIGATING: AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)

Comment: and how and where is `providerDBsnaps` initialized?

Comment: I added the initialization process, it's just a simple getting data from firestore example, do you need the full code?

Answer (score 0):

The connection state will remain in "Waiting" until a new snapshot is sent.

One way to solve it is to have your StreamBuilder inside a StatefullWidget so you can keep the state of "providers".

The function "providerListItems" could be outside the StreamBuilder, in your State class.

Then your FutureBuilder could be something like:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
    case ConnectionState.none:
    case ConnectionState.done:
      return const Text('Something went wrong');
    case ConnectionState.active:
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
        providers = documents
            .map((e) =>
                ProviderList.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList();
      } else {
        providers = [];
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  if(providers.isNotEmpty) {
    return Container(
      ...
      );
  } else {
    return const Text('No data...');
  }
```

Another way, in my opinion easier, would be to listen to your stream inside the InitState and update the providers when an event is sent.

```
class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget> {
  List providers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    providerDBsnaps.listen((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
        providers = documents
                .map((e) =>
                    ProviderList.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
                .toList();
       } else {
            providers = [];
       }
       setState((){});
    };
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if(providers.isNotEmpty) {
        return Container(
          ...
          );
      } else {
        return const Text('No data...');
      }
  }

  List<DataRow> providerListItems() {
    final List<DataRow> providerList = [];
    ...
    return providerList;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both solutions cause an error due to the providers variable (List of Providers) not being initialized yet. Is there any other way? Thanks in advance, I appreciate your quick responses.

Comment: Declare the "providers" as below, so you make sure it is initialized. 
  List<DataRow>  providers = [];

Comment: Okay, I tried it but the results are the same. Initially, it works but after renavigating, it does not show the data rather stuck at state waiting.

Comment: It is expected to stay at "waiting" status, unless the database sends an update (or you create a new StreamBuilder). That's why you have to store the data you got the 1st time in a variable and have a stetefullWidget. 
You could also have a StatelessWidget and rebuild the StreamBuilder, but you would be accessing your database unnecessarily

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I still don't quite understand how to store the data I got the first time into a variable and have a stateful widget. Can you show me an example? I tried the code that you posted above but the results are still the same...